# Ignoring files from getting added to the repo in git

Tags: git

I am learning to use git. I started with a small project and did 
`git init` inside the project directory. Then I added all files to the staging area by doing `git add *`.

But then I realized, I did not want to add a certain dir named "target" .. so I did a `git reset HEAD` and added a .gitignore file inside .git/ with the following contents

```
#python specific
*.pyc

# backup files to ignore
*~

# directories to ignore
target/
```

Now when I do `git status` I can see `/target` appearing under untracked files.

If I am not wrong, now if any already tracked file is changed and directly committed by `git commit --a` then `target/` doesn't get committed since it has not been added yet.

But what if I had to do a `git add *` again ? (for eg. to conveniently add a lot of new files created in the project) Will this dir get added to the repo ? or is it that it will get ignored but will continue to appear in the list of untracked files regardless ?

Of course I can try this out but don't want to mess things up :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've added the directory /target to your gitignore file this directory will never be added, even when you do git add *. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this, but its getting staged. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Hmm I'm no expert, but this should work (it's the whole purpose of the gitignore file). Maybe check this link: http://book.git-scm.com/4_ignoring_files.html  edit: where did you place the .gitignore file? it should be in the root folder of your repository I think.

Comment: yes the problem was with the location of .gitignore. I had put it inside .git/. Moved it to root and its working now. Thanks.